# Is c++ a space free language?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, whitespace

```
 #define PR ( A, B )  cout << ( A ) << ( B ) << endl ;
```

> - error -> A was not declared in  scope
>   - error -> B was not declared in scope
>   - error -> expected "," before "cout"

I thought C++ was space free language but when I write above code, then I see some errors.
I am still thinking "Is  my console is not working properly or library?".

If I am not wrong, how can someone say *"C++ is a space free language"*?

Comment: Whitespace matters in all useful languages.  Who is saying otherwise?

Comment: Where did you get the idea the C++ was a "space free language" in the first place?

Comment: @FredOverflow, I have read three books,all of them says same thing. I can give more specific book name ; Thinking in c++

Comment: @fatai: "Space free" usually means "without spaces", by the way. The usual term is *free-form*. C++ is a free-form language. This just means layout isn't *strictly* white-space controlled.

Comment: Even "strictly whitespace-controlled" is problematic.  I've seen more energetic arguments over whether C++ code is better spelled func( a, b ) or func(a, b) – that is, spaces inside parens or not – than I have for whitespace handling in Python, for example.

Comment: @FredNurk: I completely disagree. C# and Vb.Net tolerate spaces and allow any kind of indentation / formatting.

Comment: @SoMoS: I don't follow; what do you disagree with?  You can't disagree with my anecdote (it's mine, after all), and I don't see what C# and VB have to do with me saying "saying C++ isn't 'strictly whitespace-controlled' is problematic".

Comment: @FredNurk: I was talking about "Whitespace matters in all useful languages. Who is saying otherwise?"

Comment: @SoMoS: Ah, that makes *much* more sense. :)  Whitespace is more than just formatting (of which indentation is part), and matters in C# and VB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous exceptions where whitespace matters; this is one of them.  With the space after `PR`, how is the preprocessor supposed to know whether `(A,B)` is part of the macro expansion, or its arguments?  It doesn't, and simply assumes that wherever it sees `PR`, it should substitute `( A, B )  cout << ( A ) << ( B ) << endl ;`.

Another place where whitespace matters is in nested template arguments, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >
```

That final space is mandatory, otherwise the compiler assumes it's the `>>` operator.  (Although I believe this is sorted out in C++0x).

Yet another example is:

```
a + +b;
```

The space in between the two `+` symbols is mandatory, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, the `>>` issue is indeed sorted out in C++0x.

Comment: +1 for template definition. Have come across that many times.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a space between the macro-function-name and the parenthesis starting the argument list.

```
#define PR(A, B) cout << ( A ) << ( B ) << endl
```

Whitespace in the form of the newline also matters, because a #define statement ends when the preprocessor hits the newline.

Note that its usually a bad idea to put semicolons at the end of macro function definitions, it makes them look confusing when used without a semicolon below.

Answer (score 2):

A `#define` is not c++, it's preprocessor. The rules of c++ aren't the same as the rules of the preprocessor.

To indicate a macro, you mustn't have a space between the name and the parenthesis.

```
#define PR(A, B)  cout << ( A ) << ( B ) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for defense of a claim I've never heard anyone bother to voice...?

The preprocessor stage doesn't follow the same rules as the later lexing etc. stages.  There are other quirks: the need for a space between `>` closing templates, newline-delimited comments, string literals can't embed actual newlines (as distinct from escape sequences for them), space inside character and string literals affects them....

Still, there's a *lot* of freedom to indent and line-delimit the code in different ways, unlike in say Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the c++ preprocessor as instruction to the preprocessor (part of the compiler) and not exactly a part of the "c++ space".. So the rules are indeed different although many references are shared between the two 'spaces'..