# ## macro argument concatenation not working as I expected

Tags: c++, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Shouldn't this:

```
#define MOGSH_CONCAT (x,y) x##y
#define MOGSH_DOUBLE (a,b) MOGSH_CONCAT(a,b)
#define MOGSH_DEFINEPROC (p) MOGSH_DOUBLE(_gt,p) options_dialog::p;

MOGSH_DEFINEPROC(AssignMainForm);
```

happily expand to:

```
_gtAssignMainForm options_dialog::AssignMainForm;
```

Given that `_gt` is not defined, `_gtAssignMainForm` is:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *_gtAssignMainForm)();
```

and `options_dialog` is just a class where `AssignMainForm` is a static member.

Instead, in MSVC9, I get the error:

```
'a' : undeclared identifier
```

on the line containing

```
MOGSH_DEFINEPROC(AssignMainForm);
```

Comment: Remove the spaces between the macro name and the `(arguments)` in the definitions? That makes it work for me in gcc but I don't have MSVC to test.

Comment: FINALLY found it: possible duplicate of [? c++ space free language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814952/c-space-free-language). Can't blame you for not finding it.

Comment: Hallelua, brothers, it works! :D, thx Andy for being first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the definition of a function-like macro there can be no whitespace between the macro name and the `(` beginning the parameter list.

```
#define MOGSH_CONCAT(x,y) x##y 
//                  ^ no whitespace allowed here
```

As you have it now (with whitespace), `MOGSH_CONCAT` is an object-like macro with a replacement list of `(x,y) x##y`, which is why you are getting such strange results.